# «Марфины заботы»: строчная или прописная?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Словосочетание «М(м)арфины заботы», отсылающее к 10 главе Евангелия от Луки, надо писать со строчной или прописной буквы?

Можно ли это сравнивать с ахиллесовой пятой или сизифовым трудом?

Comment: А кто отсылает? Есть ссылка на это словосочетание?

Comment: @shampar Это цитата из книжки, которую я сейчас редактирую: «Общение с мирскими людьми, а также «марфины заботы» — так отец Паисий называл монастырскую стройку — ничуть не уменьшили его ревности к пустыннической жизни».

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Марфины заботы" пока ещё не попали в зафиксированные фразеологизмы, как то:

*антонов огонь, ариаднина нить, ахиллесова пята, геркулесовы столбы, прокрустово ложе, сизифов труд, эзопов язык* и т. п.

Однако

> со строчной буквы пишутся имена прилагательные, образованные от имен
>   собственных, но не обозначающие принадлежности в прямом смысле слова,
>   например: пушкинский стиль, толстовские взгляды на жизнь.

Вот когда эта Марфа с её заботами станет притчей во языцех (а пока не стала), мы и будем писать со строчной.

Но пока предлагаю остановиться на паллиативе, который Вы уже, собственно, и выбрали: "марфины заботы" следует кавычить, но оба слова, а не так, как нам предлагает приличное вроде издание - [РОССИЙСКАЯ ГАЗЕТА](https://rg.ru/2012/01/19/kreschenie.html):

> ...Между тем всё это нужное беспокойство - всего лишь "марфины" заботы, о
>   которых сказано: Марфа, Марфа, печешься о многом, а нужно одно. То
>   "одно" в этом празднике, что важно для спасения человеческой души, -
>   само событие Крещения Господня.

В общем, я за строчную.

Comment: Согласен с @behemothus, что кавычки — это не совсем «паллиатив», а в большей степени обозначение цитаты из речи самого о.Паисия.

Comment: Но я предлагаю кавычить не как цитату, а как нечто пока ещё неустойчивое, нетипичное. То есть в другом контексте, вне речи о. Паисия, "марфины заботы" - со строчной, два в кавычках.

Answer (score 1):

> Это цитата из книжки, которую я сейчас редактирую: «Общение с мирскими людьми, а также «марфины заботы» — так отец Паисий называл монастырскую стройку — ничуть не уменьшили его ревности к пустыннической жизни».

В таком контексте заглавная не требуется. В понимании говорящего это именно фразеологизм, он использует сочетание отвлеченно, как эпитет или характеристику. 
Впрочем, без комментария все равно не ясно, что общего нашел о. Паисий у "марфиных забот" и строительства монастыря.

Видимо это.

> Иисус же сказал ей в ответ: Марфа! Марфа! ты заботишься и суетишься о
>   многом, а одно только нужно;

Лук, 10:41-42

Я бы дал это (при необходимости и возможности) в редакторских комментариях.

Что касается кавычек, то они определяются не содержанием предполагаемого фразеологизма, а тем, что он дальше расшифровывается ("так о. Паисий назвал").

Так что все надо оставить по тексту как есть. Можно было бы и не писать, ибо все уже на этом сошлись, но тут мотивация куда важнее решения. За какой-то "паллиатив" (см. Galina Aanesova) признать не могу. Все строго по науке.

Comment: «Марфины заботы» по стройке старец Паисий противопоставлял «благой части», которую избрала Мария, то есть собственно молитве. Там сноска на Евангелие будет в книге будет, конечно.

Comment: Ok, понял..............

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли это сравнивать с ахиллесовой пятой или сизифовым трудом?

Да, вполне. Тот же тип персонажа.